# 'NOT IN' or .not() with an array coming from the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am stuck on that problem for a while.

I have a model article having an array seenby containing id of users.
I am trying to get all those articles not seen by a specific user

so in Article I got :

```
add_column :articles, :seenby, :string, array:true
```

for Example the first article has been seen by user ["1", "2", "3"]

now I have user 4 and I want to find all the article not seen by him yet
So I would have a query like

```
Article.where('4 NOT IN (?)', :seenby)
```

but that doesnt work I tried many things (with .not too) but the example which come all the time is something like that :

```
something.where('4 NOT IN (?)', ['some', 'value'])
```

or

```
something.not(field:value)
```

Here I need the seenby of the article.

Thx a lot if you can help :)

Comment: What type of database are you using?  Not every database type supports arrays.  You might be better off having a join table `Seen` that belongs to `Article` and `User`.

Comment: hello, no my array works perfectly fine, I am using postgre. Yeah I might need to create a new table indeed but I wanted to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ANY`

```
Article.where('NOT ? = ANY (seen_by)', 4)
```